# VBA script in Excel stops working like it should when I use XML mapping schema on the columns

Tags: xml, vba, excel, macros

So I have this macro VBA script in Excel that works great and deletes rows if the second column contains empty cell or the text "NULL" but when I use XML mapping on those columns these scripts stop working correctly. There has to be XML mapping in place before using these scripts. Any ideas ?

```
 Sub DelBlankRows()

       Columns("B:B").Select
       Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
       Selection.EntireRow.Delete

 With ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
   With Range("b1", Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    .AutoFilter 1, "*NULL*"
    On Error Resume Next
    .Offset(1).SpecialCells(12).EntireRow.Delete
   End With
.AutoFilterMode = False
 End With
 End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "stop working correctly"?

Comment: Well currently it deletes all the data from the table instead of only the rows which have empty cells in them.

Comment: After you filter, do you see all rows or only the ones with "NULL"?

Comment: When I use this macro and the cells are not mapped with the XML schema it deletes all the rows which have empty cells in the "B" column. Which means if a cell in the "B" column had no value or simply had "NULL" would be deleted and what I have left was only the good data or only rows that are correctly filled. But now that I've mapped the cells it deletes EVERYTHING, literally ... I'm left with only the names of the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I found a better solution which works even if the cells are mapped with XML. Here it is:

```
 Dim r As Integer
    For r = Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(r, "C") = "" Then
            Sheet1.Rows(r).EntireRow.Delete
        ElseIf Cells(r, "C") = "NULL" Then
            Sheet1.Rows(r).EntireRow.Delete
       End If
    Next
```